# Sequential ordering of non-blank cells

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I would like to sequentially order the non-blank cells in a list of words within Sheets. I am using the formula =IF(L37<>"",COUNTA($L$36:L37),"")

However the cells I am ordering are created using Concatenate so even though in some cases the Concatenate formula is outputting (what looks like) blank cells, these cells are being counted as non-blanks when I sequentially order my list (I would like these cells to be excluded / counted as blanks).

Any advice on how to get around this would be massively appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

Try the LEN function:

```
=if(len(L37)>0, COUNTA($L$36:L37),"")
```

Reference: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094081?hl=en